# Issue with creating a Histogram plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization, histogram

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but this is what the error is:

Error in `fortify()`:
! `data` must be a <data.frame>, or an object coercible by `fortify()`, not a 
object.
ℹ Did you accidentally pass `aes()` to the `data` argument?
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

q1 <- Hsall_df %>% filter(code == 118)

> ggplot(aes(x=party_label, y=nominate_dim1))+

- geom_histogram()+
- labs(x="Party", y= "First Dimension Esitmate")+
- theme_bw()

Error in `fortify()`:
! `data` must be a <data.frame>, or an object coercible by `fortify()`, not a 
object.
ℹ Did you accidentally pass `aes()` to the `data` argument?
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: You might have missed  a  pipe operator `%>%` after your first line. In your original code, you don't have data for your `ggplot()`. WIth a `%>%` , the first line is used as input ; so your variable q1 would be a `ggplot`.  (Is it what you expect?)

Comment: how does this look? B/C it's saying error object nominate_dim1 not found...

Comment: q4a <- Hsall_df %>% filter(code == 118)
summarise(nominate_dim1, na.rm=T) %>%
ggplot(aes(x=party_label, y=nominate_dim1))+
  geom_histogram()+
  labs(x="Party", y= "First Dimension Esitmate")+
  theme_bw()

Comment: i updated the answer because you had an x and y aesthetic. use geom_col() instead

Answer (score 0):

without any sample data to reproduce this, from your code it looks like you did not pipe the data before your ggplot call that is why your error says `data` must be `data.frame`. try this code below which includes the pipe operator like @VinceGreg suggested:

```
q1 <- Hsall_df %>% filter(code == 118) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=party_label, y=nominate_dim1)) +
  geom_col() +
  labs(
    x="Party",
    y= "First Dimension Esitmate") +
  theme_bw()

q1
```